# Why does my styled components transitions are not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm working on a Next.js project where the menu opens with a click on a burger button. For this I toggle a class on the button, and the styles for this class use styled-components.

When I click on the button it changes like expected, but when I add a CSS transition it's still not animated. I tested the same code in vanilla HTML and it's working well.

Where did I go wrong?

This is my code:

Burger js:

```
<BurgerStyled
    onClick={() => setIsBurgerOpen(!isBurgerOpen)}
    className={BurgerOpen}
>
    <span />
    <span />
    <span />
</BurgerStyled>
```

OnClick behaviour:

```
const [isBurgerOpen, setIsBurgerOpen] = useState(false);
const BurgerOpen = isBurgerOpen ? "BurgerOpen" : "";
```

Styled component:

```
const BurgerStyled = styled.div`
    width: 32px;
    height: 21px;
    position: relative;

    span {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        background-color: var(--gray);
        width: 100%;
        height: 3px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;

        &:first-child {
            top: 0;
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
            top: calc(50% - 3px / 2);
        }

        &:last-child {
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }

    &.BurgerOpen span {
        &:first-child {
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }

        &:nth-child(2) {
            width: 0;
        }

        &:last-child {
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
    }
`;
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I think CSS transition works only with `hover` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the property to your styled component like so:

JSX:

```
return (
  <BurgerStyled
    onClick={() => setIsBurgerOpen(!isBurgerOpen)}
    open={isBurgerOpen}
  >
    <span />
    <span />
    <span />
  </BurgerStyled>
);
```

Style:

```
const BurgerStyled = styled(({ open, ...restProps }) => <div {...restProps} />)`
  ${({ open }) => open ? ` styles open here ` : ` styles closed here `};
`;
```

What you do here: you pass the `open` prop to your styled component, and then pass all other props to the div. The `open` prop is now available in your style template string. This prevents the `open` prop to be passed to the DOM-element, because a `<div>` DOM-element has no `open` property, so passing it through to the DOM would result in warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `svg` and transition to have the desired output. Check my sample code below, it might help you.

```
  import { motion } from './framer-motion'; //install it with npm     
  
  const [isBurgerOpen, setIsBurgerOpen] = useState(false);
  const HamburgerMenuContainer = styled.div`
     display:flex;
  `;

  const MenuContainer = styled.div`
  min-width:300px;
  width:100%;
  max-width:44%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: -2px 0 2px rgba(15,15,15,0.3);
  z-index:90;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  user-select:none;
  padding: 1em 2.5em;
  `;

  const Button = styled.button`
  z-index:99;
  cursor:pointer;
  `;
  
  const Path = props =>{
    <motion.Path fill="transparent" strokeLinecap="round" strokeWidth="3" {...props}/>
  }

const transition = {duration: 0.3};
  return (
    <>
      <HamburgerMenuContainer>
        <Button onClick={() => setIsBurgerOpen(true)}>
        <svg width="23" height="23" viewBox="0 0 23 23">
          <Path animate={isBurgerOpen ? "open" : "closed"} initial={false} variants={{
            closed: {d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5",stroke:"hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"},
            open: {d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5",stroke:"hsl(0, 0%, 18%)"},
          }} 
          transition={transition}
          />
          <Path animate={isBurgerOpen ? "open" : "closed"} initial={false} variants={{
            closed: {d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5",stroke:"hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"},
            open: {d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5",stroke:"hsl(0, 0%, 18%)"},
          }} 
          transition={transition}
          />
          <Path animate={isBurgerOpen ? "open" : "closed"} initial={false} variants={{
            closed: {d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5",stroke:"hsl(0, 0%, 100%)"},
            open: {d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5",stroke:"hsl(0, 0%, 18%)"},
          }} 
          transition={transition}
          />
        </svg>
        </Button>
      </HamburgerMenuContainer>
      </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem. My Burger component was outside the header, like this:

```
function Header() {
    const Burger = () => {
        // Burger component
    }

    return (
        <Burger />
    )
}
```

I just put it like this and it worked:

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <BurgerStyled ...>
            <span />
            <span />
            <span />
        </BurgerStyled>
        // Content header
    )
}
```

Now the animation works, thanks for your answers!